# Reverse Engineering iOS Apps on a Mac OS X

Tags: ida, disassemblers

I want to learn to Reverse Engineer iOS Apps. I know exactly what I need to do and I've got almost everything set up. My iPhone is jailbroken, I have installed OpenSSH to SSH into the iPhone from my Mac and installed Cycript, otool and Clutch. Now the only thing holding me back is getting an Interactive Disassembler. Could you point me in the right direction of an IDA I could use on my Mac laptop that would feature most things and is very efficient?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best options are [IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) and [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply and linking me to the sites. Appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

very pleased to be able to answer this question.
Apple app are encrypted private account, you need to use [dumpdecrypted](https://github.com/stefanesser/dumpdecrypted) decrypt it prior to analysis.

Comment: Yeah I've seen that before but never really taken a look. I'll definitely need to now, thanks.